# pfsense firewall for public ip's

Tags: pfsense

We want to add a firewall under our cage rack for a few servers that we run virtual machines under.

After further discussion we ended up on setting pfsense under a dedicated server and run a software firewall/router for start.

The question i have is simple, our network has multiple different public ip's used by our VM's ( different networks ). How can i set pfsense to include all those IP's and have a basic filtering/firewall for the public network? I dont want to filter anything under our local network used for the replication services between our hypervisors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a virtual interface for each netwok/subnet and then assign a public IP to each one of those interfaces. Then configure the default gateway of each VM to be the IP   of the coresponding virtual interface. That way you can route and filter your traffic from pfsense.